# Can I debug while running a VS Unit Test?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I want to unit test a user component which use custom events. when doing this without using VS Unit test Framework debug.assert succeed, when doing the same thing with VS Unit Test Framework, assert fails this is illogical so I want to debug while doing Unit test with VS framework. But It seems I can't because code never pause at debug point that I set.

So is there a way to force it to pause at debug point in that case ?

Update: I mean not in the Test Project itself but in the Targeted Project while running the Test Project.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The answer by P. Campbell is not exactly right.  If you start debugging a project (such as a WCF services site), it is impossible to start any unit tests, debug mode or not.  The options to do so are simply grayed out in Visual Studio 2012.

This means you simply cannot debug out-of-process code from a unit test.  You can only debug code that was directly called in process by the unit test.

This is a major problem in VS2012 that they need to fix now.

Comment: It occurred to me you can use another instance of Visual Studio to debug your out of process code.

Comment: @ChrisBordeman that is the only way.  Open another instance, execute your tests from there and set your break point during debugging the other project.  Come on VS, you are better than that!

Comment: Using two instances of VS is a PITA, but works. Alternative: put a break point in UT, run to it, then do Debug->Attach to process. It works just fine. Have no idea why it is restricted through the UI.

Comment: In my case, I wanted to start a web api project in debug mode while running a test. Using the method @Borv suggested by putting a breakpoint in the test but instead of running Debug -> Attach, I right clicked on the web api project and ran Debug -> Start new instance. This worked for me in VS 2015.

Answer (score 58):

**Yes**, with the Visual Studio Test project, you can set breakpoints and step through your code.

Be sure to run your tests with the Debug menu -- Tests -> Debug -> Tests in Current Context.
For any given test class or test method, use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-T</kbd>.

When your cursor is in a method (*either a test method, or the code covered by the test*), it'll break on any breakpoints in that method, or any breakpoints anywhere in the code execution path. If your cursor is on the class, or in between test methods, it'll run all tests in the class. Breakpoints will be hit here as above.

Comment: I forgot I mean not in the Test Project but in the Targeted Project

Comment: @user: yep, any breakpoint will be hit, whether in the test method, or the code being tested downstream.

Comment: just to add to @user 's remark, if you debug the unit tests you will be able to stop and debug any code, the tests or the tested code AS LONG as you have the tested code source or debugger info, so you wouldnt be able to jump into a referenced dll with no symbols file

Comment: There are no specific settings because on my setup through execute but the breakdowns are never hit?

Comment: Make sure you're not in a Release build.

Answer (score 6):

In VS2015, select:

> Test->Debug->All Tests

Or you can highlight a specific test in the editor and select

> Test->Debug->Selected Tests

Comment: This also goes for VS2017.

Answer (score 0):

Under the Test Explorer -> Right click on the specific test case you want to debug -> From the Context Menu click Debug the selected test case option.