# Is it possible to interactively debug a web service while it's being executed in a Unit Test in VS2010?

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, unit-testing, visual-studio-debugging

Basically, I've got a pretty standard web service call, in a DLL project, running under the built debug server.

Looks something like this

```
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate:="")>
Public Function POSTOrder(httpPostOrder As Contract.APIOrder) As Contract.Response.Order
    ....
    Return (httpResponse)
End Function
```

If I RUN the project, I can send XML POST requests to it using fiddler just fine, and if I set a breakpoint  in the above function, it gets hit.

Now, I'd like to set up a simple unit test for this function, so I added a test project and this test:

```
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub TestPostOrder()
    Dim r As String
    Dim w As New Net.WebClient

    W.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml")
    Dim x =
            <?xml version="1.0"?>
            <order_info>
                <event_id>103153</event_id>
                <id>1</id>
                .....
            </order_info>
    r = w.UploadString("http://localhost:15034/orders/?api_key={sometext}", "POST", x.ToString)
End Sub
```

I know, not the greatest Unit Test in the world, but that's not the point right now.

So, When I run this test, it DOES run through and it's successful. I can even debug the unit test, step through it, and see that the UPLOADSTRING call does succeed and return valid information.

BUT, if I set a breakpoint in the actual function being tested, it's never hit.

I found this question

[Can I debug while running a VS Unit Test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200758/can-i-debug-while-running-a-vs-unit-test)

but I tried that and no dice.

I'm guessing I don't have something configured quite right with the unit test, and so it's not starting the actual DLL in a context that can be debugged, but so far, I've turned up nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Make sure your debugger is attached to the right process (IIS or Cassini process) that's hosting the actual service, not the Unit Test (which is only a client).

What I would do is:

- have a VS instance set to debug the web process
- use the debugging instance to set any needed breakpoints
- use another VS instance to run the test

Comment: You might be on to something, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I start one instance of VS, and run the web service project, it starts, and waits for a connection. Then I start another instance and just run the tests. The tests project has no references to the webservice projects or dlls. When I do this I get a "501 internal server error". Unfortunately, that's about all I get to go on.

Comment: I also tried attaching to the WEBDEV process within both a single instance of vs, and in the instance hosting the webservice. Same error.

Comment: and if you don't attempt to debug you get HTTP 200 OK instead of 501?

Comment: right. The service returns just fine, and responds the way I expect it to (it's actually working in production). We've been debugging by hitting it with fiddler, but that's a pretty manual process.

Comment: A possibility: it could be a timeout error, if the timeout is set to a very low value. This could work in common scenarios because the service responds quickly, but in debugging scenarios execution is delayed until you press F5. Although I'm not sure this would result in status 501.

Comment: ok. Finally resolved that. The compile target dir had been moved, which was causing a "missing reference" error, but I just didn't see it initially. With that fixed, your suggestion works great. Not ideal, as it definitely requires 2 instances of VS running, the first containing the webservice, which I just have to start, no attaching to processes. The second instance I load up with the unit test project and run the tests in debug. Doing that, I am able to debug both the tests (in one instance) and the actual webservice (in the other instance). Good deal and thanks for the pointers!